# Apparent redundancy of harmonic coordinates in GR

Tags: general-relativity

We recently saw in class that the Einstein equations have a fourfold ambiguity corresponding to our freedom to choose a set of coordinates, and then introduced a set of coordinates $X^\mu$ (harmonic coordinates) defined by

$$\nabla_\alpha \nabla^\alpha X^\mu = 0$$

Then, since the $X^\mu$ are functions and therefore $\nabla_\alpha X^\mu = \partial_\alpha X^\mu$,

$$\nabla_\alpha (\partial^\alpha X^\mu) = \partial_\alpha \partial^\alpha X^\mu + \Gamma^\alpha_{\nu\alpha} \partial^\nu X^\mu = \frac{1}{\sqrt{-g}}\partial_\alpha\left(\sqrt{-g}\, \partial_\alpha X^\mu\right) = 0$$

Now by choosing to work in these harmonic coordinates, i.e. $\partial_\alpha X^\mu = \delta^\mu_\alpha$, we find

$$\partial_\alpha \left(\sqrt{-g}\, g^{\alpha\mu} \right) = 0$$

which is a non-covariant set of four equations that are supposed to fix our gauge freedom by adding an additional set of constraints when solving for the metric (in the $X^\mu$ coordinates).

This is all well and good, but I do not see how these are not redundant. Starting again with the (covariant) condition for harmonic coordinates $\nabla_\alpha \nabla^\alpha X^\mu = 0$, I can now choose (I think) to immediately work with them, by saying $\partial_\alpha X^\mu = \delta^\mu_\alpha$. In that case, I find

$$\nabla_\alpha \nabla^\alpha X^\mu = \nabla_\alpha \partial^\alpha X^\mu = \nabla_\alpha \left( g^{\alpha\nu} \partial_\nu X^\mu \right) = \nabla_\alpha \left( g^{\alpha\nu} \delta^{\mu}_\nu \right) = \nabla_\alpha g^{\alpha\mu} = 0$$

which vanishes identically because of metric compatibility! And, because the "condition" $\nabla_\alpha \nabla^\alpha X^\mu = 0$ is covariant, this seems to vanish in any set of coordinates, making me wonder if $\nabla_\alpha \nabla^\alpha X^\mu = 0$ is actually a non-trivial condition given spacetime coordinates $x^\mu$; from what I get I seem to be able to infer that any coordinate set is automatically harmonic given, of course, metric compatibility.

Therefore I also do not understand how we fixed our gauge freedom, since I keep getting the result that the condition we imposed on our coordinates is actually an identity.

I would be very thankful if someone could explain where I am going wrong and could resolve this apparent redundancy. Thanks in advance!

Comment: $g^{\alpha\mu}$ is not a tensor in your expression, because $\mu$ is fixed. The covariant derivative is acting only on the "vector" index $\alpha$.

Comment: Ah, alright. I forgot it was just a label for each $X^\mu$ and got carried away by the notation. Thanks!

Comment: How do you prove the condition now?